# Share staging directory across tasks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I face this problem:

I have a task "Build VS" in my build pipeline, which accepts a .sln and creates a .exe file. This .exe file is saved into $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\bin.

In the following `Powershell task` I want to call this .exe file. The problem is, that `Build VS task` uses a different $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) than the `Powershell task`.

Is there a possibility to save the Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory of `Build VS task` so I can share it with my `Powershell task`?

Comment: Ho @alex1258 can you share your pipeline definition?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` is [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

It is the same and shared between tasks.

Based on your description, you can set the working directory in PowerShell task.

For example:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   # Write your PowerShell commands here.
   
   Write-Host "Hello World"
   

   
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

[image]

Then the PowerShell task will work on `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` by default.